# Weird way of calculating square root

Tags: c, math, sqrt

I've been told this code snippet is equivalent to `(int)sqrt(n)`

```
int s(int n) {
    for (int i = 1, k = 0; n > 0; i += 2) {
        if (k + i > n)
            return i / 2;
        k += i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it seem to work,
yet I don't understand how it works ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question, not a programming question. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note: code fails large `n` near `INT_MAX`.  IAC, for large numbers it takes a long time to run.  Faster methods exist.

Comment: If you think that is weird, you should see the highly bizarre algorithms inside scientific calculators.  Even after studying them for hours, there is no glimmer of how they are doing what they do!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It uses the fact that `x^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2*x-1)`. Here `i` goes over the odd numbers and `k` is their sum. It stops when the sum is more than `n`. At this point `i == (2*x-1) + 2` where `x` is the square root, so `x == floor(i/2)`.